# Substitute in place an element with two other in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Summary: Given an array

```
{a, b, ..., w, x, ..., z}
```

insert several elements `{m, n, ..., r}` in the position of `x`, also removing `x`. Final array:

```
{a, b, ..., w, m, n, ..., r, ..., z}
```

---

Have an return array

```
$return_arr = array(
                    'saa'=>'A2223',
                    'asab'=>'asB',
                    'wqed'=>'D234',
                    'wqasee'=>'Esd',
                    'wqewf'=>'Ffds',
                    'monwa'=>'monwaaas'//*
                    );
```

it will return new array if in this array exist this element 'monwa'=>'monwaaas'.And the new array will be the next order of element that we found
for example
if we have $return_arr =>the new_array should be

```
(add two more element ('hi'=>'HI','hello'=>'HELLO')

$new_array = array(
                    'saa'=>'A2223',
                    'asab'=>'asB',
                    'wqed'=>'D234',
                    'wqasee'=>'Esd',
                    'wqewf'=>'Ffds',
                    'hi'=>'HI',
                    'hello'=>'HELLO'
                    );
```

And if

```
$return_arr = array(
                    'saa'=>'A2223',
                    'asab'=>'asB',
                    'monwa'=>'monwaaas',//*
                    'wqed'=>'D234',
                    'wqasee'=>'Esd',
                    'wqewf'=>'Ffds'
                    );
```

the new_array should be:

```
$new_array = array(
                    'saa'=>'A2223',
                    'asab'=>'asB',
                    'hi'=>'HI',
                    'hello'=>'HELLO',
                    'wqed'=>'D234',
                    'wqasee'=>'Esd',
                    'wqewf'=>'Ffds'
                    );
```

And so On...

Anybody knows how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example on an online interpreter](http://codepad.viper-7.com/biVh6c).

1) Search the position of that element, 2) remove the element and 3) then insert in its previous position.

```
$pos = array_search_pos($arr, 'monwa');
unset($arr['monwa']);
$result = array_insert_at($arr, $pos, array("key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"));
```

With these functions:

```
function array_search_pos($arr, $key) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if ("$k" == "$key")
            return $i;
        $i++;
    }
    return false;
}

function array_insert_at($array, $pos, $values) {
    return array_slice($array, 0, $pos, true) +
        $values +
        array_slice($array, $pos, count($array)-$pos, true);
}
```

Comment: $return_arr = array(
                    'saa'=>'A2223',
                    'asab'=>'asB',
                    'wqed'=>'D234',
                    'wqasee'=>'Esd',
                    'monwa'=>'monwaaas',//it has problem here
                    'wqewf'=>'Ffds'
                    );

Comment: Problem if we put 'monwa'=>'monwaaas' at beginning and after the end.

Comment: @python It workds at the beginning and at the end. I'm not sure what you mean with "after the end", though.

Answer (score 0):

@Artefacto

This will keep same positions , I am sure.

$return_array will be filed as the positions in $new_array.

```
$new_array = array(
                    'saa'=>'A2223',
                    'asab'=>'asB',
                    'monwa'=>'monwaaas',//*
                    'wqed'=>'D234',
                    'wqasee'=>'Esd',
                    'wqewf'=>'Ffds'
                    );

$element_array = array('hi'=>'HI','hello'=>'HELLO');

foreach($new_array as $key=>$value)
{
        if($key == 'monwa' && $value =='monwaaas')
        {
               foreach($element_array as $key1=>$value1)
               {
                     $return_array[$key1] = $value1;
           }
        }
    else
    {
               $return_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($return_array);
echo "<pre>";
```

Please try once

Comment: this should be a comment. And I mean positions, not array keys. E.g. `array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2)` versus `array('b'=>2, 'a'=>1)`

Comment: sorry for arguing with you talented guys. But I have checked my code.
I know it is not efficient for large arrays but I think my answer was correct.
try this

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this.

```
foreach($new_array as $key=>$value)
{
       if($key == 'monwa' && $value =='monwaaas')
       {
               foreach($element_array as $key1=>$value1)
               {
                       $return_arrat[$key1] = $value1;
               }
       }
       else
       {
              $return_array[$key] = $value
       }
}
```